# BCRYPT password changing after including with 'require' PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue where a temporary stored password changes whenever the file it is stored in is included using `require` in PHP.

I'm building a CMS and am storing a password temporarily in a separate file (`temp_register.php`).

```
/* Some more PHP above */ 

require 'lib/password.php';

$pass1 = password_hash($pass1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

/* Script to store password in file below this line */
```

But whenever I want to `require` the file in another PHP script the password hash changes.

```
/* Some more PHP above */

require 'temp/temp_register.php';

/* Password is stored as $pass in that file
This line of JavaScript is for test purpose only! */
?><script>alert('<?php echo $pass; ?>');</script><?php

$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('',:username,:email,:password)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $pass);
$stmt->execute();

/* Some more PHP below */
```

I used an JavaScript alert to check if the password indeed changed, and it did.

Comment: because you have `$pass` and `$pass1`? They're two different variables. and since you're passing the hash through javascript, note that you're subject to JS parsing rules. you should NEVER dump raw text from php into a JS context. always `json_encode()` it first.

Comment: I made a comment about that in my code. `$pass1` is stored under `$pass` in the separate file I'm talking about. The passing through JavaScript is for testing purposes only. But, even if I store the hash in the database without even using JavaScript, the hash changes. @MarcB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do not pass any salt manually to `password_hash()`, it generates salt automatically. So same password can generate different hash and if you are using PHP 5.5 or greater the default algo `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` is Bcrypt so no need to include any external file.

**If you provide salt manually, your hash will never change for a password**

*Although it is not safe providing salt manually*

Using password_hash() you can hash and store hashed password. When user submit his password search database for users hashed password and verify password this way:

```
`password_verify($password , $receivedhash)`
```

If password match it will return `true` else return `false`

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.4 to make it compatible with most web hosts. Currently I'm using an external file which makes the `password_hash()` available in PHP >= 5.3.7. This script also passes salt.

Comment: But you are not providing any salt manually `password_hash($pass1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);` so hash will be different for same password. you need to use password_verify() to verify your password.

Comment: Where exactly would I have to use `password_verify()` in my code?

Comment: Thanks. Your reply helped :)

Answer (score 0):

To verify if the hash created once when the user created their account matches the current password from the login attempt, you have to use the function `password_verify()` and provide both the current clear text password as well as the stored hash from before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sven. I'm using `password_verify()` on my login page. I'm currently only focusing on storing the correct hash instead of a hash that suddenly changes.

Comment: The hash will change every time you create one from the password because it will use a random salt value. That salt value is part of the created hash string, so it can be retrieved when verifying the password with the stored hash.

Comment: I'm only creating it once, then storing it in a file, and inserting it into the database. I'm not modifying it in between.